# How do I perform advanced logic when a specific field is updated in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Say I have a three models that look (basically) like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :deliverables
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :deliverables
end

class Deliverable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Now, say I want the following to happen: when a `project` is transferred from one `user` to another, all associated `deliverables` will be transferred along with it. So something like:

```
project = Project.find(some_criteria)

deliverables = project.deliverables

project.user_id = new_user_id

deliverables.each do |d|
  d.user_id = new_user_id
end
```

Is there some way to automate what I just described? I could always of course just put that into a method (like `transfer_user`), but I would prefer for it to happen automatically whenever `user_id` is set to a new value.

Comment: Why not just remove the User's has_many :deliverables? You can retrieve a user's deliverables from the project, i.e. `user.project.deliverables`. Then you don't have to transfer at all, a new project user inherits all deliverables automatically.

Comment: @Mark: You're right; in fact, this was a contrived example not corresponding realistically to the code I'm actually working on. I apologize for including a bad example; fortunately for me, Kang's answer does address the actual scenario I'm dealing with (where the associations among models don't work out quite as neatly to allow for the solution you suggested).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably still want to implement the transfer_user method, but add a callback in your project model by doing:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :transfer_user, :if => "user_id_changed?"
end
```